# Centering y-axis titles on top of the axes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate the attached plot in ggplot. Reading other posts on SO, I have been able to figure out everything (see code, with data) except for how to center the y-axis titles--"Mask" and "No Mask"--on top of the axes as pictured. (The code puts them to the left and right of the axes.) Is there a way to do this?

[Plot to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXprQ.jpg)

```
dates <- c("07/12/2020", "07/13/2020", "07/14/2020", "07/15/2020", "07/16/2020",
           "07/17/2020", "07/18/2020", "07/19/2020", "07/20/2020", "07/21/2020",
           "07/22/2020", "07/23/2020", "07/24/2020", "07/25/2020", "07/26/2020",
           "07/27/2020", "07/28/2020", "07/29/2020", "07/30/2020", "07/31/2020",
           "08/01/2020", "08/02/2020", "08/03/2020")
dates <- factor(dates)

mask = c(25.3181818181818, 19.6883116883116, 19.6298701298701, 20.4870129870129,
         19.7467532467532, 19.7467532467532, 20.4675324675324, 19.8636363636363,
         20.5357142857142, 21.4415584415584, 19.7857142857142, 19.7857142857142,
         20.4675324675324, 19.0454545454545, 19.6493506493506, 17.0194805194805,
         16.2207792207792, 16.4545454545454, 16.551948051948, 16.0064935064935,
         16.1623376623376, 15.8311688311688, 15.9285714285714)

noMask = c(9.827922077922, 9.0974025974025, 9.3311688311688, 9.8181818181818,
           9.9155844155844,9.4675324675324, 9.4675324675324, 8.9610389610389,
           8.512987012987, 8.512987012987, 8.6883116883116, 8.4935064935064,
           9.8571428571428, 9.9155844155844, 10.090909090909, 9.5064935064935,
           9.5357142857142, 9.5746753246753, 9.9935064935064, 8.8636363636363,
           9.0487012987013, 8.8636363636363, 9.1363636363636)

data <- data.frame(date = dates,
                   mask = mask,
                   noMask = noMask)

data %>% 
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = date, group = 1)) +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(y = mask, color = "mask"), size = 1.5) +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(y = noMask + 11, color = "noMask"), size = 1.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#ffc000", "#5b9bd5")) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Mask",
                       breaks = seq(15, 25, 2),
                       expand = c(0, 0),
                       limits = c(15, 26),
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~. - 11,
                                           name = "No Mask",
                                           breaks = seq(4, 14, 2))) +
    theme_minimal() +
    expand_limits(x = c(0.5, 23.5)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=seq(0.5, 23.5, 1), colour='grey85') +
    theme(legend.position = "None",
          plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"), 
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                     hjust = 1,
                                     vjust = 1,
                                     size = 8),
          axis.title.y.left = element_text(angle = 0,
                                           vjust = 1,
                                           hjust = 0,
                                           color = "#ffc000"),
          axis.title.y.right = element_text(angle = 0,
                                            vjust = 1,
                                            hjust = 1,
                                            color = "#5b9bd5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a nice way that automatically aligns the titles for every possible size of plot window and every possible width of title text, however the code below will sort of put the titles in approximate positions by adjusting the margins to negatives and setting the `vjust` of the titles.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

# Assume `data` is from question
data %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = date, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(y = mask, color = "mask"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(y = noMask + 11, color = "noMask"), size = 1.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#ffc000", "#5b9bd5")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Mask",
                     breaks = seq(15, 25, 2),
                     expand = c(0, 0),
                     limits = c(15, 26),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~. - 11,
                                         name = "No Mask",
                                         breaks = seq(4, 14, 2))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(x = c(0.5, 23.5)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(0.5, 23.5, 1), colour='grey85') +
  theme(legend.position = "None",
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   hjust = 1,
                                   vjust = 1,
                                   size = 8),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(angle = 0,
                                         vjust = 1.05,
                                         hjust = 1,
                                         color = "#ffc000",
                                         margin = margin(r = -30, l = 10)),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(angle = 0,
                                          vjust = 1.05,
                                          hjust = 1,
                                          color = "#5b9bd5",
                                          margin = margin(l = -35, r = 5)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>